# How to initialize and return vector of vectors more compactly?

Tags: c++

How to initialize and return vector of vectors more compactly ?  The code below seems bloated and repetitious for the two cases when `K==1` and `K==N`.

```
std::vector< std::vector<unsigned int> > Foobar(const unsigned int K, const unsigned int N)
{
    std::vector< std::vector<unsigned int> > res;

    if (K == 1)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned int> r(1,N);  //One N.
        res.emplace_back(r);
        return res;
    }

    if (K == N)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned int> r(N,1);  //N ones.
        res.emplace_back(r);
        return res;
    }

    PopulateVectors(res, K+1, N+1);
    PopulateVectors(res, K, N);
    return res;
}
```

The function `PopulateVectors()` accepts `res` as a reference and inserts multiple vectors into it. The way it works internally is immaterial to this question.

Comment: Can you update `PopulateVectors` to return a 2D vector instead of just updating the one you pass by ref? Or is that code untouchable?

Comment: Don't. Keep your code readable.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That advice assumes that any compacting of the OP's code would make it less readable, which is a strong claim to make.

Comment: @cigien I stand by it; the given code is pretty much as compact as it's going to get without stripping away readability. Removing characters doesn't always improve code.

Comment: @scohe001: I could do that, but I am primarily interested in compactifying the cases when `k==1` and `K==N`. Anyway, would the code be more efficient if the function returned a 2D vector instead of modifying the 2D vector?  What if move optimizations go awry and the compiler makes an expensive copy of the `res` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (K == 1)
{
  return {{N}};
}

if (K == N)
{
  return {std::vector<unsigned int>(N,1)};
}
```

Comment: So an initializer list casts to a vector automatically ?

Comment: @george this is a specific kind of syntax for initializing a type.  While initializer lists are involved, your statement does not describe what is actually going on.  I don't have the space or confidence to say exactly what the right words are in a comment, sorry.